# Dynamically component creation

Tags: java, ajax, dynamic, primefaces, components

I created an InputText component dynamically. And then i created a valuexpression and bind it to component and i created an ajax behavior and added it to keyup event. the problem is after keyup event triggered, bounded veriable is not set. it is always null. I can see the value but it is not assigned yo bounded veriable.

I uploaded a video youtube. you can see the problem easyly. Link is under this line.

http://youtu.be/M_WXDiSp8pM

Alsoi i added codes to github. if you want, you can look.

https://github.com/kissoid/hata.git

```
`@Override`
`public void processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {`
`System.out.println(deger);`
`System.out.println(inputText.getValue());`
`System.out.println(event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("value"));`
`}`
`});`
`inputText.addClientBehavior("keyup", blurBehavior);`
`panelGrid.getChildren().add(inputText);`
`}




`<h:form id="form1">`
`<p:messages autoUpdate="true" />`
`<p:panelGrid id="deneme" columns="1">`
`<p:commandButton value="tıkla" ajax="false" actionListener="#{indexBean.islem}" update="@form" />`
`</p:panelGrid>`
`<p:outputLabel id="testLabel" value="#{deger1}" /> `
`</h:form>`
```